# How to classifiy document the Topics using Gensim LDA model after the Training(How to deploy the code)?

Tags: input, gensim, topic-modeling

I try to build a gensim LDA model for topic modeling [output of my trained model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmnU6.png). I need to give a real time input to check that document come under which topic. this model for question classification like Qunts, Reasoning and verbal question. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hari. Please specify what have you tried yourself and search for existing questions and answers. Also clarify the question and be specific. If you want to raise 2 different questions, please do post them seperately.

Comment: What do you mean by "Qunts"? Have you tried anything from the `gensim` docs for LDA (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html), and noted especially the `get_document_topics()` method, which when given a bag-of-words ('bow') representation of a document, returns its topics?